# Javascript timed refresh of div for Chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Currently, I am using the following code to refresh the `<div name="content">` portion of a web page

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   window.onload = setupRefresh;
>
>  function setupRefresh() {
>      setInterval("refreshFrame();", 5000);
>  }
>  function refreshFrame() {
>     parent.content.location.reload();
>  }
> </script>
>
> </head>
> <body>
> <div id="header">
>   <h1>Arbitrary Header</h1>
> </div>
> <div name="content">
>   <?php
>   //Code here
>   ?>
> </div>
> ```

This works great in Firefox, but Chrome just seems to ignore it.  Any suggestions on how to make Chrome work in a similar way?

Comment: Don't use `setInterval("refreshFrame();", 5000);` — instead use `setInterval(refreshFrame, 5000);`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you're trying to achieve?  Refreshing a page every 5 seconds seems like a great way to drive visitors away from your web site.

Comment: What would the `location` of the div be? I never heard of such a property.

Comment: Sure thing.  It displays the last 50 lines of a log file via PHP.  I have wrapped the PHP in the div tag, with the intent to only refresh that content, not the header/footer/anything else on the page.

Comment: You would need Ajax for that. How do you think it does work in FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
parent.location.reload();
```

as opposed to

```
parent.content.location.reload();
```

For Chrome, and it works just fine.

*Edit: This works fine on all three browsers for me.*

However, are you sure you don't want to just pull the data with AJAX calls every five seconds, instead of reloading the whole page? JQuery makes this super-easy to do, both synchronously and asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above that maybe what you need is AJAX to refresh a specific section of your page. But just in case you still want to do a full page refresh. You can try adding the following meta-tag on your header.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

This will refresh the page every 5 seconds.